# How convert lat lon to another format?

Tags: coordinate-system, pyproj

Input data

```
47,4792010000765
42,989255000241
```

Output data

```
5285360.478599999
5310336.491400003
```

But i receive

```
3643985.9453798616 
5539030.168736918
```

Whats incorrect in my code?

```
import pyproj
Lat = 47.550976
Lon = 42.963041

p = pyproj.Proj(proj='utm', zone=38, ellps='WGS84')
x,y = p(Lat,Lon)
print(f"{x} {y}")
```

Comment: can you add some explanation as to why you expected a different result?

Comment: i compare it with arcgis.

Comment: Also are you sure you want zone 32 because longitude of 42 is to the east of that by a long way.

Comment: `p(Lat,Lon)` should be `p(Lon, Lat)` according to the [documentation](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/dev/api/proj.html#pyproj.Proj.__call__)

Comment: @IanTurton how detect zone?

Comment: https://mangomap.com/robertyoung/maps/69585/what-utm-zone-am-i-in- Zone 38

Comment: @user2856 changed to 38, but same issue

Comment: Try: (long+3)/6 +30  ==> (42.9 + 3 )/6 + 30 = 38.5. Try 38.  proj +proj=utm +zone=38    <<EOF  
> 42.963041 47.550976  
> 346741.02 5268405.64  
Is it near Kotel'nikova?

Comment: @wingnut nope, its Dagestan https://yandex.ru/maps/28/makhachkala/?ll=47.479201%2C42.989255&z=19

Comment: Your long and lat are reversed. That's 47°E

Comment: @wingnut if i swap it - same issue)

Comment: It's zone 39 and (218694.99, 4762484.58)

Comment: Your easting seems very high (usually 6 digits, you have 7). The northing is probably not UTM in any zone. Did you look at Pulkovo, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arcgis store data in WGS 1984 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere).

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
print(transform(Proj(init='epsg:4326'), Proj(init='epsg:3857'), x,y))  # longitude first, latitude second.
```

Comment: That looks good. I get about 5280000, 5310000 for my dot in QGIS.